# What is the probability of seeing n number of cards at least once in a deck with k number of cards (with replacement) after r trials?

Tags: probability

Given a deck of *k* number of cards.

You shuffle the deck, and picked out *c* (*1 ≤ c ≤ k*) number of cards. After checking and recording the values. You put the cards back into the deck.

The question is: After *r* trials, what is the probability that the count of the values you recorded is larger or equal to *n* (*c ≤ n ≤ k*)?

Some of the attempts were made using **Inclusion and Exclusion**, as well as the **Stirling numbers of the 2nd kind**. I have some starting leads for the problem.

The formula used to calculate the probability for seeing all *k* cards once after *r* trials, with the number of cards picked per trial *c* = 1:
$$
p_0 = \sum_{k=0}^n(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\left(1-\frac kn\right)^r
$$
The formula used to calculate the probability for seeing all *k* cards once after *r* trials with *c* number of cards picked every trial:
$$
p_0 = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^j \binom{k}{j} \left( \frac{\binom{k-j}{c}}{\binom{k}{c}} \right)^r
$$

Some simulations/test cases (10,000,000 iterations / test):

- For *k = 9, n = 8, c = 1, r = 10: p = 8.272%*
- For *k = 9, n = 8, c = 1, r = 20: p = 81.131%*
- For *k = 15, n = 10, c = 1, r = 20: p = 92.152%*
- For *k = 20, n = 18, c = 2, r = 25: p = 85.173%*
- For *k = 10, n = 9, c = 3, r = 15: p = 99.952%*

Answer (score 0):

In each trial, the probability of not choosing Card $X$ is ${k-1 \choose c}/{k \choose c} = 1-\frac{c}{k}$. Thus, the probability of Card $X$ having been chosen at least once over $r$ trials is

$$1-(1-\frac{c}{k})^r$$

From this, we can conclude that the answer to your question is:

$$\sum_{i=n}^k {k \choose i}(1-(1-\frac{c}{k})^r)^i((1-\frac{c}{k})^r)^{k-i}$$

Comment: The answers don't match/approximate to be equal to the given simulations' result. Maybe this is not it?